# Question regarding seats.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 7 people, and 2 of them are grandma, and grandpa.

7 of them have to sit on a car, which has seats located as following:
2 seats in the front, 3 seats in the middle, 2 seats in the back.

Grandma and grandpa MUST sit in the middle.

How many possible different ways of them sitting?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, the answer depends on what is considered different seating arrangements. E.g. Are the $2$ seats in the front distinct or are they indistinguishable?

Comment: All seats are distinct, so (A, B) is different to (B, A). In the middle, considering that grandma is M and grandpa is P, (A, M, P) is different to (P, M, A), (A, P, M), etc.

Comment: I haven't done anything to it since I'm clueless on this question.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you're completely clueless.  Can you answer the question if there is no restriction of where Grandma and Grandpa sit?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first let's put Grandma and Grandpa in the middle.

You have $3$ ways to seat Grandma, and then you have $2$ ways to seat Grandpa. Then you can choose from $5$ other people to put in the last seat in the middle row.

Then, you have $4$ ways to choose a person in the drivers seat, $3$ ways to choose the person in the front passenger seat, $2$ ways to choose for the left-back seat, and only $1$ remaining way to choose the right back seat.

So, your answer is $3\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 4!=720$ ways.

Comment: Gosh, this was a lot easier than I thought. Thank you for the answer, it was very clear and understandable.